# Does an update statement in update trigger, fire trigger again?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

If I use an update statement in an update trigger, does that update statement in update trigger causes fire trigger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your database property for `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` is set to off (which is the default anyway) so that it cannot be fired recursively.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190946.aspx

Comment: Thnx it helped a lot.

Comment: `select is_recursive_triggers_on from sys.databases where name = '...DBName';` if someone is looking for that.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a trigger doesn't fire himself.

Comment: Thnx it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use, **WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
after insert or update
ON [TABLE] FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.proc_name();
```

Comment: The question is about Sql Server so please mention explicitly that this is for PostgreSQL.